# Map List Data (Sub List Data) C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, logic

I have some problem regarding multiple data.

i ll add my sample here.

```
foreach (HotelPaxRoom c in h.PaxRoomSearchResults)
{
  int index = c.index;
  foreach (RoomCategory a in c.RoomCategories)
    {
             HRoom room = new HRoom();
             room.id = a.id;
             room.category = a.category;
             room.price = a.price;
             room.index = c.index;
    }
}
```

Actually PaxRoomSearchResults has data list.i ll call PaxRoomSearchResults as A
inside that PaxRoomSearchResults has RoomCategories List i ll call  RoomCategories as B

i want to Read data using this logic.

example for A[0] vs A[1]

- A[0].B[0] ,A[1].B[0]    ---(A[0] index and B[0] first index)
- A[0].B[1] ,A[1].B[1]
- A[0].B[2] ,A[1].B[2]
- A[0].B[3] ,A[1].B[3]

example for A[0] vs A[1] vs A[2]

- A[0].B[0] ,A[1].B[0] ,A[2].B[0]
- A[0].B[1] ,A[1].B[0] ,A[2].B[1]
- A[0].B[2] ,A[1].B[0] ,A[2].B[2]
- A[0].B[3] ,A[1].B[0] ,A[2].B[3]

---

- A[0].B[0] ,A[1].B[1] ,A[2].B[0]
- A[0].B[1] ,A[1].B[1] ,A[2].B[1]
- A[0].B[2] ,A[1].B[1] ,A[2].B[2]
- A[0].B[3] ,A[1].B[1] ,A[2].B[3]

---

- A[0].B[0] ,A[1].B[2] ,A[2].B[0]
- A[0].B[1] ,A[1].B[2] ,A[2].B[1]
- A[0].B[2] ,A[1].B[2] ,A[2].B[2]
- A[0].B[3] ,A[1].B[2] ,A[2].B[3]

Like wise it goes..........
Actually i cannot do this using my foreach through.is there any better and acurate/fast way to do this?

always this should map with PaxRoomSearchResults 0th index.then 1,then2 like wise.

please ask if you have any problem regrading my question.

Actually this output i'm getting after xml deserialization.so i ll add some small part of it.that will give you some better understanding

```
  <PaxRoomSearchResults>
                    <PaxRoom RoomIndex="1">
                        <RoomCategories>
                            <RoomCategory Id="xxx:rrrr:vvv:S7519:8456:115266">
                            </RoomCategory>
                        </RoomCategories>
                    </PaxRoom>
                    <PaxRoom RoomIndex="2">
                        <RoomCategories>
                            <RoomCategory Id="xxx:rrrr:vvv:S7519:8456:33689">
                            </RoomCategory>
                            <RoomCategory Id="xxx:rrrr:vvv:S7519:8456:33707">
                            </RoomCategory>
                            <RoomCategory Id="xxx:rrrr:vvv:S7519:8456:33695">
                            </RoomCategory>
                            <RoomCategory Id="xxx:rrrr:vvv:S7519:8456:115266">
                            </RoomCategory>
                        </RoomCategories>
                    </PaxRoom>
```

result should be like this

i have separete model like this.

```
Public RoomGroup Class
  {
     public  int id {get;set;}
     public  List<RoomDetails> roomdetails{get;set;}
  }
  Public RoomDetails Class
  {
     public string roomcategoryID{get;set;}
     public decimal roomPrice{get;set;}
  }
```

output would be like this

RoomGroup 1 
             roomcategoryID   001:AMB1:7736:S7519:8456:115266
             roomcategoryID   001:AMB1:7736:S7519:8456:33689

RoomGroup 2
             roomcategoryID   001:AMB1:7736:S7519:8456:115266
             roomcategoryID   001:AMB1:7736:S7519:8456:33707

RoomGroup 3
             roomcategoryID   001:AMB1:7736:S7519:8456:115266
             roomcategoryID   001:AMB1:7736:S7519:8456:33695

RoomGroup 4
             roomcategoryID   001:AMB1:7736:S7519:8456:115266
             roomcategoryID   001:AMB1:7736:S7519:8456:115266

Comment: Yes.  Usse a for loop instead of a foreach

Comment: Please show the layout of your PaxRoomSearchResults class, and also give some sample output.

Comment: @JimMischel actually my class is little bit complex because of xml response deserialization.but i did add my sample xml response that i need to map.using my previous sample example ,i think you can figure it out.if its not please tell me

Comment: I assume that XML is the input to your algorithm. What do you want the output to be?

Comment: @JimMischel i did update my out put sample also.can you please check that one.

Comment: @jdweng Acutually its little bit complex than i thought

Comment: Not very complicated.  It looks like you have a List<RoomDetail> and want to use a GroupBy() on the roomcategory.  See msdn : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b/view/SamplePack#content

Comment: @jdweng thanks for reply,but i think you didn't read my problem.
this is not about grouping.i want to read those data besides grouping.
i can take all data to single list.
0_0,0_1,0_2 , 1_0,1_1,1_2 like wise i can give index also. but inside that list i need to read it like 0_0 --> 1_0 , 0_0 --> 1_1 ,0_0 --> 1_2 and
0_1 --> 1_0 , 0_1 --> 1_1 ,0_1 --> 1_2 like wise.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you want.  Maybe this :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<RoomGroup> roomGroup = new List<RoomGroup>() {
                new RoomGroup() {
                    id = 1,
                    roomdetails = new List<RoomDetails>() {
                        new RoomDetails() {
                            roomcategoryID = "001:AMB1:7736:S7519:8456:115266"
                        },
                        new RoomDetails() {
                            roomcategoryID = "001:AMB1:7736:S7519:8456:33689"
                        },
                    }
                },
                new RoomGroup() {
                    id = 2,
                    roomdetails = new List<RoomDetails>() {
                        new RoomDetails() {
                            roomcategoryID = "001:AMB1:7736:S7519:8456:115266"
                        },
                        new RoomDetails() {
                            roomcategoryID = "001:AMB1:7736:S7519:8456:33707"
                        },
                    }
                },
                new RoomGroup() {
                    id = 3,
                    roomdetails = new List<RoomDetails>() {
                        new RoomDetails() {
                            roomcategoryID = "001:AMB1:7736:S7519:8456:115266"
                        },
                        new RoomDetails() {
                            roomcategoryID = "001:AMB1:7736:S7519:8456:33695"
                        }
                    }
                },
                new RoomGroup() {
                    id = 4,
                    roomdetails = new List<RoomDetails>() {
                        new RoomDetails() {
                           roomcategoryID = "001:AMB1:7736:S7519:8456:115266"
                        },
                        new RoomDetails() {
                           roomcategoryID = "001:AMB1:7736:S7519:8456:115266"
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            foreach (RoomGroup group in roomGroup)
            {
                string output = string.Format("RoomGroup {0} {1}", 
                        group.id.ToString(),
                        string.Join(" ", group.roomdetails.Select(x => "roomCategoryID " + x.roomcategoryID).ToArray())
                        );
                Console.WriteLine(output);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    public class RoomGroup
    {
       public  int id {get;set;}
       public  List<RoomDetails> roomdetails{get;set;}
    }
    public class RoomDetails
    {
       public string roomcategoryID{get;set;}
       public decimal roomPrice{get;set;}
    }
}
```